# Pass the value from a datePicker (start date) to a second datePicker (end date) with React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have two datePickers (**StartDate & EndDate**) what I want to do is after I select the StartDate pass that value to the EndDate so I can choose a date after the StartDate.

For example if I choose my StartDate to be December 10 then when I go to my EndDate datepicker I wont be able to choose any date before December 10 so that will be my starting point for the EndDate datepicker.

This is my render method.

```
render() {

    const today = new Date();
    today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);

    return (
      <div className={cr.container}>
        <div className ={cr.boton}>
          <Divider/>
        </div>
        <div className={cr.rows}>
          <div>
            <div>
              <DatePicker
                hintText="Start Date"
                minDate = {today}
              />
              <br/>
              <DatePicker
                hintText="End Date"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'll appreciate the help on this...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? Nothing according to you code sample?

Comment: I just clean the code because I had a mess =( I tried some stuff like creating a second constant like this "const endDate = {startDate}" but didn't worked...

Comment: I just start learning react js and also js so I have some gaps that I'm covering reading some books and stuff but I decided to do some examples..

Answer (score 2):

Try updating the component state after selecting the start date:

```
<DatePicker
    selected={this.state.startDate}
    onChange={this.handleChangeStart}
    hintText="Start Date"
    minDate={today}
/>
```

... And then for your end date component, try using that value fore `minDate`

```
<DatePicker
    selected={this.state.endDate}
    onChange={this.handleChangeEnd}
    hintText="End Date"
    minDate={this.state.startDate}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this if you are using material-ui date picker:

```
<DatePicker
   hintText="Start Date"
   minDate = {today}
   onChange={(null, date) => { setState({ startDate: date }); }}
   value={this.state.startDate}
/>

<DatePicker
   hintText="End Date"
   defaultDate={this.state.startDate + 1}
   {/* or however you calculate endDate */}
   value={this.state.endDate}
   onChange={(null, date) => { setState({ endDate: date }); }}
/>
```

See the [controlled example](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker) from the docs.